# VBA .Add Cells - Set start Cell location

Tags: vba, excel

I need this VBA to pull all file names, Link them and place them in column A2 and down in +1 increments

```
Sub GetFileNamesInfolder()

    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim Folder As Object
    Dim File As Object
    Dim Path As String
    Dim A As Integer


    Path = "\\server5\Operations\MainBoard testing central location DO NOT REMOVE or RENAME"

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder(Path)
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        A = A + 1
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(A, 1), File.Path, , , File.Name
    Next
End Sub
```

how would you approach this?

Comment: I'd approach it similarly to what you have above (that code works just fine).  Is there a question here somewhere?

Comment: If "how would you approach this?" were worded as "is there any way this code could be improved?", then you would have something like a [codereview.se] question. As it stands though, it's *too broad* for Stack Overflow and rather *unclear* for Code Review.

Comment: If you want to start in A2, initialize A to 1 before your `For` loop.

Comment: I am a noob and would like some help initializing cell A2 I am trying to figure it out looking at other examples but it is just not working for me.

Comment: @JimHewitt Thanks that seems to work